# Is there an rspec matcher to confirm a class includes a library, module or gem?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Found this tutorial using minitest, and was wondering if there is an equivalent matcher in rspec:

[Interesting minitest assertion](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/writing-an-api-wrapper-in-ruby-with-tdd/)

```
describe "default attributes" do

  it "must include httparty methods" do
    Dish::Player.must_include HTTParty
  end

  it "must have the base url set to the Dribble API endpoint" do
    Dish::Player.base_uri.must_equal 'http://api.dribbble.com'
  end

end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Testing if a class has included a module is generally wrong, as you are testing implementation details instead of expected behavior.

Included modules can be found by calling `ancestors` on the class, so you can simply use `include` matcher:

```
expect(Dish::Player.ancestors).to include(HTTParty)
```

Your second expectation should be tested with:

```
expect(Dish::Player.base_uri).to eq 'http://api.dribbble.com'
```

**EDIT**

Until today I did not know that classes implement the `<=>` operator. You can simply check if `Dish::Player < HTTParty`.

Answer (score 1):

You can test if a class directly includes a module directly with:

```
expect(described_class < MyModule).to eq(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `be_kind_of` it also works for included modules:

*"expect(obj).to be_kind_of(type): calls obj.kind_of?(type), which returns true if type is in obj's class hierarchy **or is a module and is included in a class** in obj's class hierarchy."* -- https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/type-matchers

```rb
  it { is_expected.to be_kind_of(HTTParty) }
```